# Testing a Function within React JS Jest Testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, unit-testing, jestjs

I am working on testing in Jest and am looking for a way to test a specific Function that has a Change so I need to make the test simulate a change.

this is my Test

```
it('Expect HandleFilterChange', () => {
    const handleFilterChange = jest.fn();
    handleFilterChange();
    const handleChange = wrapper.find("noJava8")
    console.log("this is what Handle Change Equals ",handleChange)
    expect(handleChange).toEqual("")
    handleChange.simulate('lowCodeCoverage', { handleFilterChange: 27 });
    expect(store.getActions()[0]).to.deep.equal(noJava8);
    expect(handleFilterChange).toHaveBeenCalled()
 })
```

and this is my code

```
handleChange = name => event => { console.log(name)
var options = {lowCodeCoverage: this.props.lowCodeCoverage, noBasePOM: this.props.noBasePOM, noJava8: this.props.noJava8};
options[name] = event.target.checked;
this.props.handleFilterChange(options);
console.log(this.handleChange)
```

};

```
<FormControlLabel
                  control={<Checkbox checked={this.props.lowCodeCoverage} 
onChange={this.handleChange('lowCodeCoverage')} 
value="lowCodeCoverage" color="primary" />}
                  label={I18n.t('filters.low-code-coverage')}
                />
                <FormControlLabel




 <WithStyles(FormControl) component="filter-options">
        <WithStyles(FormGroup)>
          <WithStyles(FormControlLabel) id="lowCodeCoverage" control={{...}} label="low-code-coverage" />
          <WithStyles(FormControlLabel) id="noBasePom" control={{...}} label="no-base-pom" />
          <WithStyles(FormControlLabel) id="noJava8" control={{...}} label="no-java-8" />
        </WithStyles(FormGroup)>
```

Comment: How are you doing shallow rendering here ?

Comment: wrapper = shallow(<FilterOptions />)    Its defined above in the file

Comment: add your render method code too

Comment: added it to the original question

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate `change` event like this:

If `noJava8` is the id of `FormControlLabel`, it's my assumption.

```
const handleChange = jest.fn();
wrapper = shallow(<FilterOptions.WrappedComponent handleChange= {handleChange}  />).dive();
wrapper.find('#noJava8').simulate('change');
expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This test will be passed.

Comment: I reveived this error     Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.

Comment: have you added the `id` on formLabel?

Comment: added that and now im receiving this     "Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called."

Comment: Edited my answer. It was `change` instead of `click`

Comment: still the same issue arrises.

Comment: Please do this:  console.log(wrapper.debug())

Comment: added it to my original question

Comment: @JakobLong I have edited my answer please use WrappedComponent and dive for HOCs